# fetch user's facebook url with the facebook login ids

Tags: android

I am developing an android application which allow user to add their facebook page url by providing their facebook log in details, since I am new to android and have no idea how to do this, any help will be greatly appreciated. some code will be even better, thanks!

Comment: A little more information is needed. Why do people have to give you/ your application their login details? What do you mean with "facebook page url", do you mean their profile? What's the use of having to add their "Facebook page url", how does the application need it?